# Steam API, different json format

Tags: javascript, node.js, steam-web-api, discord.js

Recently i integrated CSGO stats in my discord bot, but today i saw that for almost every player the API sends a different json data.

Here 2 examples:

https://jsonblob.com/58688d30-26d0-11e8-b426-7b3214778399
https://jsonblob.com/52ed0c3f-26d0-11e8-b426-43058df4a5a6

My question was how to request the data properly so a win is really a win and not a kill.

```js
 .addField('**Wins:**', `${object.playerstats.stats[5].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Time played:**', `${object.playerstats.stats[2].value}` + ' minutes', true)
 .addField('**Kills:**', `${object.playerstats.stats[0].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Deaths:**', `${object.playerstats.stats[1].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Bombs planted:**',`${object.playerstats.stats[3].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Money earned:**',`${object.playerstats.stats[7].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Knife kills:**',`${object.playerstats.stats[9].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Headshot kills:**',`${object.playerstats.stats[24].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Dominations:**',`${object.playerstats.stats[39].value}`, true)
 .addField('**Rounds played:**',`${object.playerstats.stats[44].value}`, true)
```

Answer (score 2):

The `name` property of stats items appear to be unique enough to find. You can use [`array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to look for the correct stat by name.

```
const stats = object.playerstats.stats
const totalKills = stats.find(s => s.name === 'total_kills').value
const totalDeaths = stats.find(s => s.name === 'total_deaths').value
```

Taking it further, you can use [`array.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to generate an object whose key is `name` and value is `value` for each item in the array. This way, you access it like an object.

```
const stats = object.playerstats.stats
const statsObj = stats.reduce((c, e) => (c[e.name] = e.value, c), {})

const totalKills = statsObj.total_kills
const totalDeaths = statsObj.total_deaths
```

Comment: beat me to it :D the .reduce approach is pretty nice and better than the actual find, since you just loop the stats array once instead of multiple times

Comment: Agreed that .reduce() is preferable to .find(), but you may wish to tweak your .find() callbacks to do an equality comparison (`s.name === 'total_kills'`, for instance) so that .find() works correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying to reference the array indexes, why not convert the API response into an easier-to-parse format?

```
// do this once...
let playerStats = {};
object.playerstats.stats.forEach(s => playerStats[s.name] = s.value);

// ...then you can use the playerStats variable however you need:
.addField('**Kills:**', `${playerStats.total_kills}`, true)
.addField('**Wins:**', `${playerStats.total_wins}`, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The stats array is just not sorted. you can use .find() to get the correct entry from the stats.

for example

```
const totalWins = object.playerstats.stats.find(stat => {
    return stat.name === 'total_wins';
});
.addField('**Wins:**', `${totalWins.value}`, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are approching this problem the wrong way.

JSON is not a format that is ordered. What that means is that there is no guarantee that the JSON data will return in the same order everytime. It is not a default of the API.

There is one way you could still use your way: by sorting the 'stats' array by name. but it is a long operation and not a very good idea.

The way do to this is to do a lookup by name.
For example, if you want to find the wins, you do this :

```
object.playerstats.stats.find(elem => elem.name === 'total_wins').value;
```

The **find** function does a lookup and returns the first element matching the predicate (elem.name === 'total_wins'). It returns null if not element matched the predicate (so be careful here).

You could do a function that returns a value for you :

```
findValue(statsArray, name) {
    const entry = statsArray.find(elem => elem.name === name);
    return entry ? entry.value : '?';
}
```

And then your code would look like this :

```
 ...
 .addField('**Wins:**', findValue(object.playerstats.stats, 'total_wins'), true)
 ...
```

The main thing here is : **never assume fields in a JSON will return the same every time.** Always use lookup, and not indexes (unless it is sorted).